# Vectorised implementation raise KeyError when using loc directly to assign value based on condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

After reading a csv file

```
Date,Description,Price
15/11/2020,Red blah,51
13/11/2020,blah Blue,24
10/11/2020,Green blah,10
09/11/2020,blah Green,21
08/11/2020,blah Blue blah,42
```

I wish to add a new column (`category`) and give it a string value if any of the substrings in a list (`keys`) is contained inside another column's (`description`) string.

I have managed to achieve this using a `for` loop but when I try to implement it **using a vectorized solution it raises a KeyError**:

> KeyError: "None of [Index(['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Green', 'Blue'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"

even thought that key clearly exists.

My code:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('my.csv',
                     header=0,
                     names=['date',
                            'description',
                            'price'],
                     dayfirst=True,
                     parse_dates=True)

keys = ['Green', 'Blue']
df['category'] = ''

# with for loop
for index in df.index:
    if any(key in df.loc[index, 'description'] for key in keys):
        df.loc[index, 'category'] = 'CYAN'
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'category'] = 'NOT CYAN'

# with vectorized solution raises KeyError
# df.loc[any(key in df.loc[df['description']] for key in keys), 'category'] = 'CYAN'
# df.loc[any(key not in df.loc[df['description']] for key in keys), 'category'] = 'NOT CYAN'

print(df)
```

The above code with the `for` loop returns the expected:

```
         date description  price  category
0  08/11/2020        Blue     42      CYAN
1  09/11/2020       Green     21      CYAN
2  10/11/2020       Green     10      CYAN
3  13/11/2020        Blue     24      CYAN
4  15/11/2020         Red     51  NOT CYAN
```

Any suggestions on how to imlement the above using a vectorised approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where`:

```
df['category'] = np.where(df['Description'].isin(keys), 'CYAN', 'NOT CYAN')
```

Output:

```
        Date Description  Price  category
0 2020-11-15         Red     51  NOT CYAN
1 2020-11-13        Blue     24      CYAN
2 2020-11-10       Green     10      CYAN
3 2020-11-09       Green     21      CYAN
4 2020-11-08        Blue     42      CYAN
```

---

**Update**: For substring, use `str.contains`:

```
pattern = '|'.join(keys)

df['category'] = np.where(df['Description'].str.contains(rf'{pattern}'), 
                          'CYAN', 'NOT CYAN')
```

Output:

```
        Date     Description  Price  category
0 2020-11-15        Red blah     51  NOT CYAN
1 2020-11-13       blah Blue     24      CYAN
2 2020-11-10      Green blah     10      CYAN
3 2020-11-09      blah Green     21      CYAN
4 2020-11-08  blah Blue blah     42      CYAN
```

Comment: numpy's `where` seems great, thanks. But please note that the `keys` is a subset; I modified the question to make it explicit in the example. Is there a way use the `np.where` so that it matches for when the keys list is a subset of the description column?